# Prepend icon before td that will be changed with .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, font-awesome

I have tds that need to have their values changed. Doing so with:

```
$(".class td:nth-child(2)").html("new value");
```

But I am trying to append font-awesome icons before this value with:

```
$(".class td:nth-child(2)").append("<i class=\"fa fa-arrow-up\"></i>");
```

which puts the icon after the html. I want it to be before the html. It looks like I need to append because html clears the class information. How do I put the icon before the html dynamically?

Comment: Then use `.prepend()` http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Comment: I just changed the question for you. `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `prepend()` to add content to the beginning of a parent element instead:

```
$(".class td:nth-child(2)").prepend("<i class=\"fa fa-arrow-up\"></i>");
```

http://api.jquery.com/prepend

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if a method like this existed. Does exactly what I need.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend):

```
$(".class td:nth-child(2)").prepend("<i class=\"fa fa-arrow-up\"></i>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use CSS3 and assign a before/after to a class and just change the class in jQuery.

Example:
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dbg4zbe4/)

In your case something like:

```
//The Css
.arrow-up:before {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 25px; 
  width: 25px;
  padding-right: 5px; 
  content: '<i class=\"fa fa-arrow-up\"></i>';
}

//The jQuery
$(".class td:nth-child(2)").addClass("arrow-up");
```